# Adding click event to span without class or id and with strong html tag

Tags: jquery

I tried various ways but couldn't find a solution. How can I add a jQuery click event to a span which has strong element without any class or id?

I want to add click event to only span which uses a strong tag and a specific text content:

```
<span onclick="redirect('/home')"><strong>Home Page</strong></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `:has` modifier to match an element that contains an element matching another selector, and `:contains` to match the text.

```
$("span:has(strong:contains(Home Page))").click(function() {
    redirect('/home');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span').has('strong:contains("Home Page")').click(function () {
redirect('/home');
})
```